# jquery, determine object position using component width

Tags: jquery, html, styles

i want to put the position  of inner div with using:

```
 <div id="outerdiv">
     <div id="innerdiv1" style="position:absolute;width:30px;"
     <div id="innerdiv2" style="position:absolute;left:20px;"
```

The problem is width of innerdiv1 can be changed dynamically, i want that div2 is near to div1, i calculate its position using outerdiv1.left + innerdiv1.innerwidth, but there is always some offset and innerdiv2 is not exactly put to innerdiv1? What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using component.outerWidth instead of component.width, it will give the exact result.